# MongoDB PHP driver fatal error with Windows

Tags: php, mongodb

I am getting this error: `Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found` when trying to get the PHP driver working for MongoDB.

I know that this kind of question has been asked a lot because I've read through a ton of them. Everything I try isn't working. I have followed the instructions from: http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php

This includes downloading the correct `php_mongo.dll` file and putting it in my ext folder. I have also added `extension=php_mongo.dll` to my php.ini. The mongo details do not appear when I run `phpinfo()`. I have also downloaded and installed MongoDB from: https://www.mongodb.org/downloads#production

System Details:

- PHP Version: 5.6.13
- x64 architecture
- Apache Version: 2.4.16

Any suggestions for this?

Comment: Thanks everyone, the fix worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I had the same problem as you and after sifting through much information it came down to enabling the proper extensions in your ini file. Mine was on line 736, it was commented out. Looks like this "extension_dir = "c:/php56/ext" ", uncomment this and add the src path like my example e.g C:/php/ext

Answer (score 1):

You check on line 736 on the php.ini if its commented or not the extension_dir = "c:/php56/ext"